# ASP.Net Web API 2 method not showing correct data but row count is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have written a method in Repository class for which I have created a Controller in Web API project. 
Following is my Model class:

```
namespace Meijer.Merch.Space.Data
{
    public class FloorplanAnalyst
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }

        public string EmpName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Following is the method in Repository class:

```
public IEnumerable<FloorplanAnalyst> GetFloorplanAnalyst()
        {
            return this.Database.SqlQuery<FloorplanAnalyst>("GET_FLOORPLAN_ANALYSTS").ToList();
        }
```

Following is my Controller method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace SpaceWebApi.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controller used for the retrieving of FloorplanAnalyst information
    /// </summary>
    public class FloorplanAnalystController : ApiController
    {
        private ISpaceRepository db = new SpaceRepository();

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of FloorplanAnalysts.        
        public IEnumerable<FloorplanAnalyst> GetFloorplanAnalyst()
        {
            return db.GetFloorplanAnalyst();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting following records as my result (27 rows are returned):

```
    {
        "EmpId": 0,
        "EmpName": null
      },
      {
        "EmpId": 0,
        "EmpName": null
      }
}
```

In SQL Server correct data is returned when the stored procedure is executed. But at Web API end it is not correct.

Comment: Is GET_FLOORPLAN_ANALYSTS as stored procedure ?

Comment: yes it is a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue because `EmpId` and `EmpName` properties into `FloorplanAnalyst` class don't match the columns name returned by your `GET_FLOORPLAN_ANALYSTS` stored procedure.

To solve this, make sure that each property have an associated column name (same name as the property) in the result query from your stored procedure.

Comment: I cannot change my stored procedure column names but I need EmpID and EmpName at front end. How do I make it possible?